# installing Vue-edit-json not working using npm

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am trying to get this https://github.com/dirkliu/vue-json-editor editor to my project and as its stated on the instructions i am running `npm install Vue-edit-json --save` but it gives me this error:

```
Timocins-MacBook-Pro:s360auth timocinzaynal$ npm install --save Vue-edit-json
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: Vue-edit-json@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/timocinzaynal/.npm/_logs/2018-12-16T10_49_18_730Z-debug.log
```

Is anybody else having this problem? If not what is different with me?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/dirkliu/vue-json-editor) you linked indicate the installation command is:

```
npm install vue-json-editor --save
```

But you tried a different (and nonexistent) package name:

```
npm install Vue-edit-json --save
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```